# Capture clicks on elements with ID in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to capture click on elements with ids stored in array `ids`.

E.g:

```
ids = ['item1','item3','item4']

<a href='' id='item1'></a>
<a href='' id='item3'></a>
<a href='' id='item4'></a>
```

When clicking on 3 it should return 3 and prevent redirect.

Comment: hey man - you got any jsfiddle? cheers

Comment: You cannot have IDs that begin with a digit. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Comment: What do you mean by _"return 3"_ what is the DOM structure? did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If return 3 means alert 3...

```
$.each(ids, function(index, value) {
    $('#' + value).click(function(event) {
        alert(this.id);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nnG99/)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville. Easy question, typo... :)

Comment: Could you upload a fiddle? For some reason I cannot make it work.